# Example of O(n!) algorithm without recursion

Tags: algorithm

It is trivial to write a O(n!) algorithm with recursion, but can someone give me an example of a O(n!) algorithm using just iterations without recursion?

Comment: Your question is not well-defined. Iteration vs recursion is an implementation detail and not intrinsic to algorithm. E.g., There's an algorithm to enumerate permutation which takes O(n!). You can implement it using either recursion or iteration.

Comment: I guess I was asking for an example in code, not an algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A trivial way is to count from 1 to n!, where you compute n! by products.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of the [N-Queens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle), solved by a brute-force approach, takes O(N!) time.

The problem is basically positioning N queens in a NxN chess table without any of them being able to kill another.

The brute-force solution consider that, in the first step, you can try N slots of the first column, then N-1 slots of the second, ..., until you test the only possible position in the N-th column, hence you have O(N!).

Answer (score 1):

> Could you please point me to a how you could generate all possible permutations without recursion?

Sure. Here's a Python program that generate all possible permutations *with recursion*:

```
N = 4
arr = [0] * N
def permute(n):
    if n == N + 1:
        print(arr)
    else:
        for i in range(N):
            if arr[i] == 0:
                arr[i] = n
                permute(n + 1)
                arr[i] = 0
permute(1)
```

and here's one that does so *without recursion*

```
N = 4
arr = [0] * N
stack = [(1, 0, "do-it")]
while stack:
    n, i, state = stack.pop()
    if state == "do-it":
        if n == N + 1:
            print(arr)
        else:
            if arr[i] == 0:
                arr[i] = n
                stack.append((n, i, "cleanup"))
                stack.append((n + 1, 0, "do-it"))
            else:
                stack.append((n, i, "no-cleanup"))

    if state == "cleanup":
        arr[i] = 0

    if state in ["cleanup", "no-cleanup"]:
        if i + 1 < N:
            stack.append((n, i + 1, "do-it"))
```

The trick is to notice that recursion uses call stack, so if you want to avoid recursion, then roll your own stack whose each element captures the essence of your program state.

Comment: Whether the stack is built-in or explicit makes no difference. Recursion is about temporarily saving the context *somewhere*.